# About Linux Auditd log

Tags: linux

In audit.log, I can see:

> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1646113477.615:531): arch=c000003e syscall=3
> success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=7ffcadf66ae0 a2=7ffcadf66b60 a3=8 items=0
> ppid=1431 pid=1451 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0
> sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=19 comm="bash" exe="/bin/bash" key=(null)
>
> type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1646113477.615:531): proctitle="-bash"

The question is: How can I get the closed file name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ausearch`. See more info [on the RedHat pages](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-understanding_audit_log_files), but to summarise:

> The a0 to a3 fields record the first four arguments, encoded in hexadecimal notation, of the system call in this event. These arguments depend on the system call that is used; they can be interpreted by the ausearch utility.